# Wordpress displaying unistalled plugin

Tags: wordpress

I installed and uninstalled wordpress plugins but they're still showing. Waht might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the plugin folder directly on the server and also clear your cache.

Comment: I have already deleted the folder, what cache should I clear?

Answer (score 0):

> Might be you have only rights to read/write on plugins directory. Try by making chmod 777 for plugins directory so have full rights on that.

Comment: I have permission on the folder, plugin. I even deleted the plugins from the plugins folder.

Comment: Is it with every plugin you installed,, or with some specific plugin